# Exec after forking a process doesn't return the result before the program finishes

Tags: c++, c, pipe, exec, fork

I'm trying to make a program that forks once and while the parent waits for the child terminates, this child forks again and then executes two execs. There is a Pipe on the program and I've checked the return values of every dup2() and pipe() on the program -just omitted them here to make it looks more concise-. The problem is that I only get the result of ls -a | sort -r AFTER the program finishes.
The code is:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
printf("Shell> \n"); fflush(stdout);

pid_t pid1;
pid_t pid2;
int status = 0;
int fd[2];

if(pipe(fd) < 0) {
    printf("FATAL ERROR.\n");
}   

pid1 = fork();

if(pid1 > 0) {      // Parent
    waitpid(pid1, &status, 0);
    printf("\t\t------PID1 Complete-------\n\n");                   
}
else {              // Child
    if(pid1 == 0) {
        printf("ON CHILD\n");

        pid2 = fork();

        if(pid2 > 0) {  // Child -> Parent
            printf("ON CHILD-Parent\n");
            close(fd[1]);
            dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            waitpid(pid2, &status, 0);
            printf("ON CHILD-Parent after wait\n");
            execlp("sort", "sort", "-r", NULL);
            perror("Problem with execlp\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else {          // Child -> Child
            printf("ON CHILD->Child\n");
            close(fd[0]);
            dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            execlp("ls", "ls", "-a", NULL);
            perror("Problem with execvp\n");
            exit(1);
        }               
    }   // End of if(pid1 == 0)
}   // End of Child

printf("\nEnd of program.\n");

return 0;
}
```

My current output is:

```
Shell> 
ON CHILD
ON CHILD-Parent
ON CHILD->Child
ON CHILD-Parent after wait
```

I think the problem is on the waits, but I just can't figure out how to make this work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I believe that int fd[2]; contains fd[0] == 0, fd[1] == 0, since it is never assigned. You then go and close fd[1] and expect fd[0] to work. This might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: I'm able to do it without the double forking, using the same idea, so I'm not sure if it is really the problem... I think that my program is waiting "forever" due to the wait().

Comment: @Robert: The contents of `fd` are assigned when the pointer to `fd` is passed to `pipe(fd)`.

Comment: @Xaphanius: Why are you doing `waitpid(pid2, &status, 0);`?  That could cause the program pid2, which is ls, to go to sleep because it is trying to write to a full buffer, which won't get read because pid1 is asleep waiting on pid2.  This is a deadlock situation, but I don't think that is your problem.

Comment: @nategoose I am using this wait function in order to wait for the ls to finish before I sort it. I see what you are saying, is there any other way to wait for the child process finish before executing ls?

Comment: @Xaphanius: Why do you want to wait for it?  What purpose does that serve?

Comment: I'm just trying to execute this command:
ls -a | sort -r
If I don't use that wait, isn't it possible for the sort program starts to run before the ls program? I'm waiting for the children finishes its process before starting the parent exec.

Comment: @Xaphanius: If the sort starts before the ls then sort tries to read its stdin and then blocks until there is some data for it to read in.  That will happen when ls writes some stuff to its stdout.  The pipe feature of Unix and Linux would allow you to pass infinite amounts of data between the processes (as long as the receiver is consuming some data) since both programs are put to sleep if they try to do an operation that can't happen because the pipe buffer is full (unless the files are in non-blocking mode, which is a more advanced thing and not affecting this).

Comment: If the ls output is large, you are likely to block. Leave it out.

Comment: A ran a strace -f ./program. The sort process is waiting on an unfinished read. I can see ls closing standard out. I don't understand why sort doesn't understand the file is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you call `pipe` in the grandparent process. After the grandchild process (ls -a) exits, the parent process (sort -r) blocks indefinitely waiting to read more input from the pipe since some process - the grandparent - holds an open descriptor to the write end of the pipe.

If you close the pipe descriptors in the grandparent process, or better yet move the `pipe` call into the first forked process, then the sort process will terminate when the last process with an open descriptor for the write end of the pipe exits ([**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e288d020556e54f7)):

```
int main() {
    // Turn off buffering of stdout, to help with debugging
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    printf("Shell> \n");

    pid_t pid1 = fork();
    if(pid1 < 0) {
        perror("fork failed");
    }

    if(pid1 > 0) {      // Parent
        int status;
        waitpid(pid1, &status, 0);
        printf("\t\t------PID1 Complete (%d) -------\n\n", status);
    } else {              // Child
        printf("ON CHILD\n");

        int fd[2];
        if(pipe(fd) < 0) {
            perror("pipe failed");
            return 1;
        }   

        pid_t pid2 = fork();
        if(pid2 < 0) {
            perror("fork failed");
        }

        if(pid2 > 0) {  // Child -> Parent
            printf("ON CHILD-Parent\n");
            close(fd[1]);
            dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            execlp("sort", "sort", "-r", NULL);
            perror("Problem with execlp");
            return 1;
        } else {          // Child -> Child
            printf("ON CHILD->Child\n");
            close(fd[0]);
            dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            execlp("ls", "ls", "-a", NULL);
            perror("Problem with execvp");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("\nEnd of program.\n");
}
```

The other problem with the program is the one [@nategoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352868/exec-after-forking-a-process-doesnt-return-the-result-before-the-program-finish/28354662#comment45051741_28352868) commented on: the call to `waitpid` could lead to a deadlock if the output of "ls -a" is too large to fit in the pipe's buffer. There's no reason to wait, so it should simply be eliminated.

Comment: That worked! I'll change the pipe creation to after the fork now. Thank you @Casey!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a real answer, but I have some into that I'd like to share.

To make sure that your output comes out in the order that it should, I'm flushing a lot more than you were.  Remember that when you are calling functions like `fork()`, `clone()`, `vfork()`, `dup()`, `dup2()`, `close()`, or any of the `exec()` family of functions you are doing stuff that is BELOW the C runtime environment, which includes `stdio`.  If you do:

```
printf("cat");
fork();
fflush(stdout);
```

You are very likely to get:

```
catcat
```

as your output because you've duplicated the stdout structure, including all buffered data, so unless stdio decided that it was time to flush anyway before the end of the printf function, then "cat" is in each process's stdout buffer.

There's also the fact that since data can stay buffered when you run a function in the `exec` family your data may not be flushed before your program is replaced with the new program.  When your program is replaced by `ls` or `sort` then any data pending in stdout gets lost forever.

Also, when you use `dup` you have the another issue since you are swapping the file descriptor out from under stdio so it may not have flushed yet and the data may end up getting flushed to the new file after the dup.

Because of these things you should have a lot more calls to `fflush`, but I don't think that's your problem here.